# secure javascript password with RESTful API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, http, rest

If I have a RESTful api that requires a username/password to use, what is the best way to do this with JavaScript? I'd like to not expose the password to the public, but any solutions are welcome.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Keep in mind the user/pass will be hardcoded into the application.

Comment: I don't think you should be too welcoming of solutions that expose passwords to the public :-)

Comment: This is a unique situation in that minifying the JS file itself might be good enough (the data is not THAT secure). However, I would like a better solution.

Comment: @DanielA.White OAuth requires a federation, this is overly complex.

Comment: Assuming the site is for the use of members of the public, then you can't give the browser the password without giving it to the public. DRM doesn't work.

Comment: I only realised now that it has to be hard-coded into application and deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that is sent to the client can be reverse engineered.

You should use tokens that are randomly generated every few hours and work like sessions. However n a pinch the next best option would be to hash the password somehow and hide it in obfuscated/minified code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just post the data to your api using https. It would be no different than posting the data in a form to https.